# Comparing strings and printing row R

Tags: r, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have a data frame, with two columns

```
'V1'     'V2'
joe      hi, my names is *joe*
anne     i was talking to *jake* the other day...
steve    *anne* should have the answer
steve    *joe* and I will talk later
```

I want to take the list of names in col 1 and use that to search for them in col 2.

(the asterisk are just to show that the names are inside long strings.)

What I really want is to say, for every entry in column one, if you can also find it in column two, then print the row.

I've tried this

```
for (i in dft[1]) if (i == dft[2]) print(i)
```

The idea is to count the number of times they appear in each column and end up with something like

```
V1    V2    V3
joe   1     2
anne  1     1
jake  0     1
steve 2     0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You say "for every entry in column one, if you can also find it in column two, then print the row," but then you say "the idea is to count the number of times it appears in each column."  Which do you want, row number or number of occurrences?  Also, please update the example output to be what you would like it to be given your example input (i.e. who's jake?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to count the number of times that each element of the first column occurs in each column, you can do something like this

```
dat <- data.frame(V1=c("joe", "ann", "steve", "steve"),
                  V2=c("hi, my name is *joe*", 
                       "i was talking to *jake* the other day...", 
                       "*anne* should have the answer",
                       "*joe* and I will talk later"), 
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

t(sapply(dat$V1, function(x) cbind(length(grep(x, dat$V1)), length(grep(x, dat$V2)))))

#      [,1] [,2]
#joe      1    2
#ann      1    1
#steve    2    0
#steve    2    0
```

`sapply` will apply a function to each element of column `V1`.  In this case, the function will count the number of times that element appears in column `V1` and column `V2` and `cbind` them together.  `sapply` will simplify the results into a matrix.  Finally, `t` will transpose the matrix into the form you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `grep` isn't vectorized over its first argument, so you have to `mapply` it.

```
dat <- data.frame(V1=c("joe","anny"),V2=c("hi, my name is joe","blah anne"))
mapply( FUN=function(x,y) grepl(x,y), x=dat$V1, y=dat$V2 )
```

That gives you a logical vector you can use to subset or sum for display purposes.

Comment: Using the OP's data, this gives `TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE`